# bytecode difference for finally block

Tags: java, jvm, code-coverage, bytecode, try-catch-finally

The same source code is compiled on the server and locally, generating different bytecodes for finally block

Bytecode compiled by the server：

```
L70
 LINENUMBER 243 L70
 INVOKESTATIC com/demo/utils/DashboardManager.log (Ljava/lang/String;JLjava/util/Map;)V
L71
 LINENUMBER 245 L71
 ALOAD 9
 ATHROW
L47
 LINENUMBER 246 L47
FRAME CHOP 2
 ALOAD 2
 ARETURN
```

Locally compiled bytecode：

```
L70
 LINENUMBER 243 L70
 INVOKESTATIC com/demo/utils/DashboardManager.log (Ljava/lang/String;JLjava/util/Map;)V
 ALOAD 9
 ATHROW
L47
 LINENUMBER 246 L47
FRAME CHOP 2
 ALOAD 2
 ARETURN
```

Two more lines of statement for the server version：

```
L71
LINENUMBER 245 L71
```

What factors may cause this difference?

Source code:

```
235:        } catch (Exception ex) {
236:            CLogManager.error(logLocal, ex, addInfo);
237:            response = BuildServiceResponse.BuildErrorResponse(UserInfoStatusCode.ServerException, ex.getMessage());
238:        } finally {
239:            metricTags.put("status", null == response ? "-1" : response.resultMsg);
240:            metricTags.put("code", null == response ? "-1" : String.valueOf(response.resultCode));
241:            DashboardManager.log(TokenServiceMetric.GetUserInfoShare_RequestCount, 1, metricTags);
242:            DashboardManager.log(TokenServiceMetric.GetUserInfoShare_ResponseCount, 1, metricTags);
243:            DashboardManager.log(TokenServiceMetric.GetUserInfoShare_CostTime,
244:                    System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime, metricTags);
245:        }
246:        return response;
247:    }
```

Comment: What versions of javac are used in each case (including minor version)?

Comment: The only difference I see is what line the "invisible" re-throw is attributed to and I'd say that one is basically pointless anyway. Is it a problem that different bytecode is generated or are you just curoious? If it's a problem then you must certainly work that both sides use the exact same software and configuration to have a chance to get identical bytecode.

Comment: @Michael Both are 1.8.0-144

Answer (score 0):

The two bytecode paths between them are identical. However, the former looks like it's got an extra entry in the `LineNumberTable` attribute.

If you use `javap -v -c` on the class, you'll see that the actual body of the bytecode is identical between the two.

I've recently [given a talk](https://alblue.bandlem.com/2020/06/bite-sized-bytecode.html) on the way bytecodes work; on [page 15](https://speakerdeck.com/alblue/bite-sized-bytecode-and-classloaders?slide=15) of the deck you'll see that the LineNumberTable attribute is an addition to the method:

[image: Picture of bytecode showing LineNumberTable attribute]

So the question is why the compiler is doing different things. It's possible that you're using a different set of compile options (e.g. `-g` or `-O` although the latter has very little difference).

It's possibly more likely that you're not using the same compiler, even though the JDK is the same. For example, your local machine you might be compiling with `javac` while the server is compiling with `mvn` (or vice versa). Typically tools like `Tomcat` will use a different compiler based off of `ecj` rather than deferring to the system compiler, and it's possible that's what the difference is between the two.